# Unable to debug first simplest Python script in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Just installed VS Code 1.20.1 on my Mac OSX 10.13.3 and am following a tutorial on LinkedIn. I'm getting an error when trying to run a simple "Hello World" script, and can't figure out the solution.

Here's my script, and my launch.json section relevant to this debug run.

```
#
# Example file for HelloWorld
#

def main():
  print('hello world')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Screen grab of VSCode Hello World Python script

[image]

```
{
    "name": "Python",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "stopOnEntry": true,
    "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
    "program": "${file}",
    "cwd": "",
    "env": {},
    "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
    "debugOptions": [
    "RedirectOutput"
    ]
},
```

My launch.json file

[image]

Comment: What is the error you are getting when trying to debug? The screenshot doesn't contain any errors, it seems to be working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `program` attribute of your `launch.json` file is set wrong. [`${file}`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_predefined-variables) (as you set it) tells vscode to use the current file for debugging, so the `launch.json`. So just change that entry to the following:

```json
"program": "${workspaceFolder}/path/to/your/helloworld_start.py"
```

To get started with python and vscode I would recommend you the [official docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python).

Comment: I'm also very new to VS Code, but apparently this problem I had is that there's this statement in launch.json:  "stopOnEntry": true,     I changed this to false so it no longer stops at the first line of executable code, and now it's running.

Comment: The same as I.  The 'stopOnEntry' is not default attribute, but added flowing other's tutorial 。After remove it ,everything is OK.